# Lambda function returning bad value in Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, function, lambda

I am learning Python. And I just learnt about lambda function.

***Problem:***

1. When I try to make a Quadratic Equation Roots Checker, I can't use the "if" statements. "d" function is causing this error - TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'
2. Why is this line appearing in the output: `<function <lambda> at 0x015AA100>`

---

---

***Code:***

```
import math

d = lambda a, b, c : (b**2-(4*a*c))
print("Equation's Form:  ax2 + bx + c")
print("Discriminant = ", d(3,4,9))
print(d)
```

***This is the output:***

```
Equation's Form:  ax2 + bx + c
Discriminant =  -92
<function <lambda> at 0x015AA100>
```

**I  want to add these lines to the code, but it displays the above mentioned error:**

```
if d < 0:
    print("Roots are unequal and imaginary")
elif d == 0:
    print("Roots are real and equal")

if d > 0 and (d - int(d) == 0):
    print("D is > 0 and Perfect Square - Thus Roots are Real, unequal and rational")
else:
    print("D is > 0 but not a Perfect Square - Thus Roots are Real, unequal and irrational")
```

Comment: that line is appearing because you print(d), and d is a *function* located at that specific address in memory. What you perhaps mean to do is to assign the output of d(3,4,9) to another variable and test this one using the if/else statements

Comment: This worked, TY warped.

Answer (score 0):

"d" is a lambda, and you're trying to print a function. You need to call the function with proper arguments to get a int number and check whether the **result** is <0, ==0, etc..

```
dd = d(3,4,9)

if dd < 0:
    print("Roots are unequal and imaginary")
elif dd == 0:
    print("Roots are real and equal")
```

Comment: Thanks bud. I got it to work. With passing the value into a variable like that.